# How to stop windows from updating?

Tags: windows-7, automatic-update

I have disabled my Windows update feature.

But some how windows downloaded the updates (I think Avast had enabled automatic updates) and it is forcing to to update my Windows 7 or it is going to run automatically 20  Feb at 3:00 am.

[image]

How do I stop it from updating?

Thanks.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by “disabled”? Did you try both setting the Windows Update setting to *don’t do it* in the Windows Update configuration and disabling the Windows Update service?

Comment: Don't run programs that do things you don't like.  If Avast installs updates you don't want, then don't use it.  There are plenty of other free antivirus programs, from experience I can say that AVG never installs Windows updates behind your back.

Comment: @Ben Voigt I can't say Avast did it behind my back as I am not sure, there's a option that says `your computer is not fully protected. click here to fix now` and may be my brother pressed it, which enabled windows update.

Comment: If you think your brother is changing your settings, then maybe give him a non-admin account (or at least configure UAC to ask for a password before elevating a process).  That way no programs can make system changes without your approval.

Comment: @Ben Voigt He did it accidentally without knowing about the windows update, if this thing happens again I am going to switch to AVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To completely disable Windows Updates, make sure to set Windows Update to **Never check for updates** in *Windows Update -> Change Settings*, and also to disable the Windows Update service in `Services.MSC`.